# dplyr filter using qdap::which_misspelt OR dplyr filter with a nested function

Tags: r, dplyr, qdap

A small data frame:

```
words <- data.frame(terms = c("qhick brown fox",
          "tom dick harry", 
          "cats dgs"))
```

If I use `qdap::which_misspelled` I can find out missspelled words:

```
> which_misspelled(words)
      1       8 
"qhick"   "dgs"
```

But what I want to do is to subset words df on the rows that contain misspelling. The above returns index 1 and 8 referring to all words provided in my df, regardless of which row.

How can I subset my df based on any rows that contain misspelled words?

(Bonus if can be done with dplyr filter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just use `check_spelling` which is vectorized, and the result contains a column of row numbers you can use to subset the data frame:

```
library(qdap)
words[check_spelling(words$terms)$row,,drop=F]

#            terms
#1 qhick brown fox
#3        cats dgs
```

---

The `which_misspelled` function seems meant to check for a single string instead of a data frame:

> which_misspelled - Check the spelling for a string.

Comment: This is great thank you. What does drop = F do? I mean, I see that if I leave it out it returns `[1] qhick brown fox cats dgs       
Levels: cats dgs qhick brown fox tom dick harry` but whats happening here?

Comment: The `drop = F` is used to keep the result as a data frame as you've noticed. There is a behavior that when you subset a data frame and the result contains only one column, it defaults to a vector for convenience purpose. So here if you want to keep it as a data frame, use `drop=FALSE`.